# Passing an image between two apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two apps, App A and App B. When I press a button in App A then App B will be called. In-App B, it has camera activity and some other image processing options like cropping, adjusting brightness and contrast. After image processing, I need to pass the image to App A. But, the image should not be saved in sd card.

**What I tried** : Using image to base64 string

**Step1:** I called AppB using this code

```
Intent i = new 
Intent("com.appb.ImageProcessingActivity");
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

**Step2:** In App B, After image processing, I convert the image to a base64 string and send it back to App A using this code. (After image processing, image size will be < 150kb)

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("outputImage", base64ImageString);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

**Step3:** In App A, I will get the image details using this code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==100 && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

        String outputImage = data.getStringExtra("base64ImageString");
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(outputImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);

    }
}
```

But I can not receive base64 String form App B to App A. It shows following error (**Note:** I can send normal string using this method)

```
JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 1058260)
```

**This answer is not accepted**

In App B, Saving the image in sd card and send image path to App B, then converting image path to base64 in App A, and then delete the sd card image.

Comment: Get rid of the base64 stuff, and send back the `byte[]` of the JPEG of the photo. This will still need to be fairly small, but it naturally will be much smaller than a base64-encoding of the JPEG.

Comment: Agree on @CommonsWare point. Please have a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried byte[] also. but, I still facing the same issue.
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            outputBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] food = stream.toByteArray();

Comment: If you want to exchange between some apps and don't want to store the image on the disc, a ContentProvider might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700680/writing-custom-content-provider-for-photos-on-phone-part-2

Answer (score 0):

First of all they are called activities not "Apps".

Second, you got that error because the image is too large to be passed between activities like that. If you look closely in your logcat you will probably find this error somewhere "**TransactionTooLargeException**".

To avoid it and to make your app works faster you should save the image as a file in the external cache directory and pass its path to the second activity and then load it. And don't worry the image will be saved only temporarily since it's in the cache directory.

Comment: hi. They are two different separate apps only.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Comment: hmm my mistake. I recommend my approach anyway because I had a similar problem like yours and by applying this you will take under consideration any image size taken by any device. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable("Bitmap", bmp);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

SENDING APPLICATION-

```
Button sendImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        sendImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        });

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                sendImage(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    void sendImage(Uri selectedImageUri) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedImageUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send Image"));
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

RECEIVING APPLICATION

```
private Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout linearlyt = new LinearLayout(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        linearlyt .addView(tv);
        linearlyt .setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {

                tv.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
                tv.append("\n" + (intent.getExtras().getString("MyKey")));

            } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                Uri uri = (Uri) bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                img.setImageURI(uri);
                linearlyt .addView(img);
        }

        } else {
            // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
        }
        setContentView(linearlyt);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. AppA and AppB are two separate applications. So, I used startActivityForResult, not startActivity. Can you please confirm your answer @Dhanshri

Comment: Anyway, I tried this, This code may work for between two activities. But, it is not working for between two applications

Comment: I tried for sending image to other application.Please check this once@Vignes

Comment: You are passing image URI, the URI image is actually stored in sd card only.

Answer (score 0):

From the times of Android 2, each application was given enough RAM to store one camera image and not enough to store two camera images. I do not think it is possible, **but** you might try `android:largeHeap="true"` in the manifest, but OTOH I don't think it would work either.

Well, as a last resort, you might create a service (within one of your applications, probably in a separate process) and send image bytes to or from that service. But are you sure it is worth the trouble? The problem is that the system may decide to kill one of two applications that have a camera image in the heap.

Or, probably, you can create a ContentProvider and store your image there. Google gives me pages like [Share an image with a content provider in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082417/share-an-image-with-a-content-provider-in-android-app)

And one more idea, really crazy: split the image into pieces of the size that may be passed via an Intent and pass it in multiple Intents :)

Comment: Does the `largeHeap` attribute increase the max. Bundle size as well? This topic is not about a heap memory issue.

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" is not helped me

Comment: ContentProvider won't help me, because I need to call app B via intent only

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

**add this line onActivityResult() in activity**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
String str = data.getStringExtra("image");
filePath = Uri.parse(str);
}
```

**using getIntent() try using data.getStringExtra() in your onActivityResult()**

it helps you

Comment: The error is occurring in  AppB itself. I can not come back to AppA

Comment: This is the error in logcat. 
JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 1058260)

Comment: When a add base64 string in putExtra. Ex, data.putExtra("outputImage", base64ImageString);  . If I put normal string then it is working fine.

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: sure. please check

Comment: http://codesfor.in/how-to-upload-image-to-server-as-base64-encoded-string/
check this link may be it helps you ....pls let me know

Comment: I checked. This link to upload the image file to the server. But, I need to send image between two separate apps.